# Tengo éste error Warning: Attempt to read property "num_rows" on bool

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Estoy intentando tomar los datos de una base de datos pero me aparece este error Warning: Attempt to read property "num_rows" on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\leccion_php\conect.php on line 17. Estoy tomando un curso de php y mysql de Udemy y ya revise el código de arriba a abajo y aún no se cual sea el problema. Espero puedan ayudarme y gracias.
Este es el código:

````
//conection to server and database
$serverName = "localhost";
$userName = "root";
$passwordServer = "";
$dbName = "lession";
//conection for mysqli
$cnx = new mysqli($serverName, $userName, $passwordServer, $dbName);

//check conecction 
if($cnx->connect_error){
    die ("Conection failed: ".$cnx->connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, email, date FROM users";
$result = $cnx->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    //out data for rows
    var_dump($result);
    var_dump($sql);
    while($row =$result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "Id: ".$row['id']." - Name: ".$row['firstName']." ".$row['lastName']." - Email: ".$row['email']."<br>";
    }
}else{
    echo "0 results";
}   
$cnx->close();
?> ```
````

Comment: Hola! Debes de mostrar el código del archivo conect.php, pues el error está en la línea 17. Asumo que el código publicado no es de dicho archivo porque en la línea 17 hay un comentario.

Comment: En efecto ese es el archivo conect.php solo que me equivoqué de línea, el lio está en que el `num_rows` aparece como bool en lugar de int, y necesito que sea el que especifique el número de filas, me expliqué?

Comment: Un paseito por la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query): la función `query` retorna `false ` si la consulta no fue exitosa, o un `mysqli_result` si tuvo éxito (en este caso con el `select`). Probá hacer el `var_dump($result)` _antes_ del if, a ver qué devuelve.

Comment: el `var_dump()` me retorna un valor false, qué función debería usar entonces, por fa, me sería útil y gracias

Comment: ¿Los nombres de campo son correctos y existen en la tabla? De ser el caso, revisa las [palabras reservadas de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) y verás que el problema es por el campo `date`. Deberías encerrar los campos entre acentos graves para evitar el error: `$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, email, \`date\` FROM users";`. De preferencia, hazlo con todos.

Comment: si, los nombre y ubicaciones son correctas, probaré los acentos entre campos. Ya lo probé y sigue igual

Comment: Error:SELECT command denied to user 'nailuj'@'localhost' for column 'id' in table 'users'bool(false)